# how can I fix my inputs which are out of range?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to fix my html/bootstrap style,but at the moment when I clicked the event all my imputs are out of range as picture number 1 at the moment when I get some input wrong . however I want to fix my inputs and when I click my event and get error from jquery stay on the same place as the picture 2

html

```
 <form id="new_product">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" title="product description" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label for="cost_price">Cost Price: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cost_price" name="cost_price" title="cost_price" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label for="selling_price">Selling price: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="selling_price" name="selling_price" title="selling_price" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label for="wprice">Wholeprice: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="wprice" name="wprice" title="wprice" required>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <label for="min_stock">Min stock: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="min_stock" name="min_stock" title="min_stock" required>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label for="stock">Stock: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock" name="stock" title="stock" required>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <label for="max_stock">Max stock: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="max_stock" name="max_stock" title="max_stock" required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

[form_view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZQO9.png)

[form_view2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7oL9.png)

jquery validation

```
 $('#add').on('click',function(){
        $("#description").mask("(999) 999-9999");
        $("#new_product").validate();
        BootstrapDialog.show({
            type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_PRIMARY,
            message: function(dialog) { 
                var $message = $('<div></div>');
                var pageToLoad = dialog.getData('pageToLoad');
                $message.load(pageToLoad);

                return $message;
            },
            data: {
                'pageToLoad': URL_GET_VIEW_PRODUCT
            },
            closable: false,
            buttons:[{
                id: 'btn-ok',
                cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-send',
                label: ' Save',
                action: function (e) {
                    var description = $('#description').val();
                    var cost_price = $('#cost_price').val();
                    var selling_price = $('#selling_price').val();
                    var wprice = $('#wprice').val();
                    var min_stock = $('#min_stock').val();
                    var stock = $('#stock').val();
                    var max_stock = $('#max_stock').val();
                    if($("#new_product").valid()){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: URL_GET_ADD_PRODUCT,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {description: description, cost_price: cost_price, selling_price: selling_price, wprice: wprice, min_stock: min_stock, stock: stock, max_stock: max_stock}
                        }).done(function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            if (data.msg == 'successfully added') {
                                $('#new_product')[0].reset();
                                table.ajax.reload();
                            }else if(data.min_stock == 'el stock no puede ser mayor al min'){
                                BootstrapDialog.show({
                                    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING,
                                    message: 'el stock no puede ser mayor al min'
                                });
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            },{
                id: 'btn-cancel',
                cssClass: 'btn-danger',
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                label: ' Cancel',
                action: function (e) {
                    e.close();
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean your "inputs are out of range?" This is just html. The wording of your issue suggests that there is a problem with validation but you provided no code. I suggest you provide your code and try to clarify the expected and observed behavior.

Comment: I mean when I write some some text on the wrong input. update code jquery